# display pop up working in addtocart.phtml but not in custom .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, popup

We are using below code in **addtocart.phtml** to display **pop up box**  once we click on **"save design**" buttton, its working fine.

```
<div class="ajaxlogin-login" id="productlistlogin" style="display:none;">Click Here</div>

<div onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();">
    <button class="button btn-cart">Save design</button>
</div>
```

we are using same **onclick code** for another button present in below phtml file :

`onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();`"

app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/template/aitcg - js_styles1.phtml

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<div class="ajaxlogin-login" id="productlistlogin" style="display:none;">Click Here</div>

<script>

_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}">save design</button>' +
                '<button>reset</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

    /**
     * Init Apply and Reset buttons events
     */
    initObservers: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
        }
    },

    submitApply: function(event)
    {
        Event.stop(event);
        this.option.apply();
    },

</script>
```

but after this **Product view page** will become **blank** , There is no errors in log files

[image]

**Edit**

**console error** after click on "save design" in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: custom .phtml full code : http://pastebin.com/MxPmaiE1

Comment: Try with onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>');setrequestlogin();"

Comment: @JaiminSutariya now page loaded, but `save design` button not displaying......  link : [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

Comment: @JaiminSutariya there is syntax error in [console](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#) : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

Comment: in view page source its displaying : `<button onclick="setproductlogin('19960');setrequestlogin();"  id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}">save design</button>'` //19960 is correct product id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below,

```
<div onclick="setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\');setrequestlog‌​in();">
    <button class="button btn-cart">Save design</button>
</div>
```

It should remove your "Unexpected Number" error.

Comment: yes, now `save design` button displaying, but  once we click on `save design` pop up is not displaying...... its adding the product....

Comment: in this code : `'<button onclick="setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\');setrequestlog‌​in();" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >save design</button>' +` we are using both `1) onclick 2) id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}` , also as you know in some other file once we click on `save design` we are saving product and creating new image in server..... is it anything like that code is overriding this one ?

Comment: I think I am confused about your requirements here. :)

Comment: please join : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55681/pop-up

Comment: @JaiminSutariya My add to cart button not working in CMS Page, could you pls help me to solve this -> https://justpaste.it/49eqz

Answer (score 1):

in your `app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme1/template/aitcg - js_styles1.phtml` file change below line

instead of

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

try below

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>
```

Comment: Updated code, now page loaded, but `save design` button not displaying , showing some console errors :  please check : http://pastebin.com/8WLVfSrP

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me again & again, need your support like this only in upcoming days also.....